# datetime Timeseries in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, dictionary

I want to create a python dictionary who's key is a datetime with half-hourly intervals over a year.
I have this code:

```
 import datetime as dt
 sDate = dt.datetime(2012,7,1,0,0)
 eDate = dt.datetime(2013,6,30,23,30)
 half_hour = dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
 number_readings = 17520
 dictFilled = {(sDate + half_hour * x) : 'data' for x in range (0,number_readings)}
 print(dictFilled)
```

I want the dict to look like this:

> {2012-07-01 00:00:00: 'data', 2012-07-01 00:30:00: 'data', 2012-07-01
>   01:00:00: 'data'........}

but I get this output:

> {datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 22, 10, 30): 'data', datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 24, 20, 0): 'data', datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 18, 6, 0): 'data'...}

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `datetime` are objects in Python. You want to print a representation of these objects. To do this you can use the `str()` function. Your code would be :

```
import datetime as dt
sDate = dt.datetime(2012,7,1,0,0)
eDate = dt.datetime(2013,6,30,23,30)
half_hour = dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
number_readings = 17520
dictFilled = {str(sDate + half_hour * x) : 'data' for x in range (0,number_readings)}
print(dictFilled)
```

which would give you :

```
{'2012-07-01 01:00:00': 'data', '2012-07-01 07:00:00': 'data', ...}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  This works, but I'd like to keep the dictionary key as datetime objects (so I can search for gaps and fill them). Can I do this and then convert to a string when I print or export to a file?

Comment: Yes you can, you can use your original code for filling up the dictionary and use the `str()` function whenever you need to. You can loop over the keys and values of your dictionary using `items()` and print each item.